# CSS, PHP, HTML Active Dropdown Link Issue

Tags: php, html, css, list

so I have been having an issue with some PHP strings that I can't seem to figure out. The goal is to have the "parent" link remain as an active state whilst allowing the dropdown function to contine.

```
<li class="<?php echo($activePage == "releases" ? "active" : "")?>" class="dropdown">
  <a href="releases.php" class="dropdown-toggle">Press <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li class="<?php echo($activePage == "releases" ? "active" : "") ?>"><a href="releases.php">Releases</a></li>
    <li class="<?php echo($activePage == "clips" ? "active" : "") ?>"><a href="clips.php">Press Clips</a></li>
    <li class="<?php echo($activePage == "assets" ? "active" : "") ?>"><a href="assets.php">Press Assets</a></li>
   </ul>
</li>
```

So the goal here is to get the **PRESS** link to show an active state when either of the three **releases**, **clips** or **assets**

You'll notice in the first list I have two classes at the moment. The PHP echo class when infront does display the **PRESS** link its active state however doesn't allow for any drop down, thus rendering the other three links invisible, when I place the other class in the front, the drop down works but then the **PRESS** link doesn't show an active state.

Can anyone solve this issue for me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: technically, this seems more like a CSS/HTML issue than PHP...

Comment: Sweet input man, thanks!...

Comment: You should't have 2 `class` attributes. If you want to apply two classes use: `class="class1 class2"`. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_class.asp

Comment: @WesFoster yea, I knew that. It still doesn't work so I thought I would try adding a second class. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the setup I used for a site to make the active parent element stay highlighted, as I walked down the tree:

```
#navigation ul.nav > li:hover ul a:hover, 
#navigation ul.nav > li:hover, #navigation ul.nav > li:hover ul li:hover {
background: #3e4b51 none repeat scroll 0 0 !important;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

The menu setup is this:

```
<nav id="navigation" class="col-full" role="navigation">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li>
            <a href="https://example.com/">HOME</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="https://example.com/level-1/">Level 1</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li>
                    <a href="https://example.com/level-2/">Level 2</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="https://example.com/level-3">Level 3</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="https://example.com/level-4-1">Level 4 Item 1</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="https://example.com/level-4-2">Level 4 Item 2</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```